# This Apple ID is valid but is not an iCloud account

Tags: macos, icloud

I have reviewed the askdifferent question here: ["This Apple ID is valid but is not an iCloud account"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27450/this-apple-id-is-valid-but-is-not-an-icloud-account)  - I hate to open a new question on this topic, but none of the answers or suggestions have worked for me.

I can login to iCloud.com using the ID and can access mail, etc. with no problems.  I have tried logging into iCloud in System Preferences and I get the error in the title.  I have tried adding the iCloud ID to the user in "Users and Groups" and also without the iCloud ID there and I get the same error.  I have rebooted multiple times.  I have applied all available security updates to the system.

I have run out of things to try...  System information is shown below.

---

```
EtreCheck version: 3.0.6 (315)
Report generated 2016-10-26 10:54:44
Download EtreCheck from https://etrecheck.com
Runtime 9:19
Performance: Below Average

Click the [Support] links for help with non-Apple products.
Click the [Details] links for more information about that line.

Problem: Other problem

Hardware Information: ⓘ
    MacBook Pro (17-inch, 2.4GHZ) 
    [Technical Specifications] - [User Guide] - [Warranty & Service]
    MacBook Pro - model: MacBookPro3,1
    1 2.6 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo CPU: 2-core
    4 GB RAM Upgradeable - [Instructions]
        BANK 0/DIMM0
            2 GB DDR2 SDRAM 667 MHz ok
        BANK 1/DIMM1
            2 GB DDR2 SDRAM 667 MHz ok
    Bluetooth: Old - Handoff/Airdrop2 not supported
    Wireless:  en1: 802.11 a/b/g/n
    Battery: Health = Check Battery - Cycle count = 111

Video Information: ⓘ
    GeForce 8600M GT     - VRAM: 256 MB
        Color LCD 1152 x 720

System Software: ⓘ
    OS X Mavericks 10.9.5 (13F1911) - Time since boot: less than an hour

Disk Information: ⓘ
    Hitachi HTS722020K9SA00 disk0 : (200.05 GB) (Rotational)
        EFI (disk0s1) <not mounted> : 210 MB 
        Macintosh HD (disk0s2) /  [Startup]: 199.06 GB (134.61 GB free)
        Recovery HD (disk0s3) <not mounted>  [Recovery]: 650 MB 

USB Information: ⓘ
    Apple Inc. Built-in iSight 
    Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller 
    Logitech USB Receiver 
    Apple Computer Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad 
    Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver 

Gatekeeper: ⓘ
    Mac App Store and identified developers

Kernel Extensions: ⓘ
        /System/Library/Extensions
    [loaded]    com.Logitech.Control Center.HID Driver (3.6.0 - SDK 10.6 - 2016-10-26) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.Logitech.Unifying.HID Driver (1.2.0 - SDK 10.6 - 2016-10-26) [Support]

System Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [loaded]    com.apple.coremedia.videodecoder.plist (2010-10-21)
    [not loaded]    5 Apple tasks
    [loaded]    143 Apple tasks
    [running]    36 Apple tasks

System Launch Daemons: ⓘ
    [failed]    com.apple.DumpPanic.plist (2013-10-27)
    [not loaded]    50 Apple tasks
    [loaded]    137 Apple tasks
    [running]    60 Apple tasks

Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [running]    com.Logitech.Control Center.Daemon.plist (2012-05-24) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist (2016-07-11) [Support]
    [running]    com.micromat.TechToolProAgent.plist (2014-07-10) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist (2013-06-18) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.p5sys.jump.connect.agent.plist (2016-10-25) [Support]

Launch Daemons: ⓘ
    [loaded]    com.adobe.fpsaud.plist (2016-09-23) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.google.keystone.daemon.plist (2016-08-31) [Support]
    [running]    com.micromat.TechToolProDaemon.plist (2014-07-10) [Support]
    [loaded]    com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist (2013-06-18) [Support]
    [running]    com.p5sys.jump.connect.service.plist (2016-10-25) [Support]

User Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [loaded]    com.apple.AddressBook.ScheduledSync.PHXCardDAVSource.9169C628-3317-4620-AA58-0054BCCE8809.plist (2012-07-18)

User Login Items: ⓘ
    Dropbox    Application  (/Applications/Dropbox.app)

Internet Plug-ins: ⓘ
    Flip4Mac WMV Plugin: 2.4.0.11 (2011-12-13) [Support]
    FlashPlayer-10.6: 23.0.0.185 - SDK 10.9 (2016-10-11) [Support]
    QuickTime Plugin: 7.7.3 (2016-10-26)
    Flash Player: 23.0.0.185 - SDK 10.9 (2016-10-11) Outdated! Update
    Java Applet: Unknown (2011-08-11)
    Default Browser: 537 - SDK 10.9 (2014-10-02)
    LogitechDeviceDetection: 1.0.0.76 - SDK 10.7 (2012-04-07) [Support]
    Loki: 3.4.2.20 (2011-08-11) [Support]
    Google Earth Web Plug-in: 7.1 (2015-07-24) [Support]
    Silverlight: 4.0.60531.0 (2011-12-13) [Support]
    JavaAppletPlugin: Java 8 Update 111 build 14 (2016-10-23) Check version

Safari Extensions: ⓘ
    jbsearch - jbsearch - http://www.yahoo.com (2015-04-05)

3rd Party Preference Panes: ⓘ
    Flash Player (2016-09-23) [Support]
    Flip4Mac WMV (2011-06-30) [Support]
    Java (2016-10-23) [Support]
    Logitech Control Center (2012-09-20) [Support]
    TechTool Protection (2014-07-10) [Support]

Time Machine: ⓘ
    Skip System Files: NO
    Mobile backups: OFF
    Auto backup: NO - Auto backup turned off
    Volumes being backed up:
        Macintosh HD: Disk size: 199.06 GB Disk used: 64.44 GB
    Destinations:
        Big 500 [Local] 
        Total size: 499.74 GB 
        Total number of backups: 2 
        Oldest backup: 11/5/12, 1:01 AM 
        Last backup: 11/5/12, 1:01 AM 
        Size of backup disk: Adequate
            Backup size 499.74 GB > (Disk used 64.44 GB X 3)

Top Processes by CPU: ⓘ
        34%    mdworker(4)
        20%    JumpConnect(2)
         3%    WindowServer
         2%    Dropbox
         1%    fontd(2)

Top Processes by Memory: ⓘ
    172 MB    Dropbox
    147 MB    mds_stores
    119 MB    com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
    90 MB    JumpConnect(2)
    86 MB    ocspd

Virtual Memory Information: ⓘ
    0 B    Free RAM 
    0 B    Used RAM (1.83 GB Cached)
    0 B    Swap Used 

Diagnostics Information: ⓘ
    Oct 26, 2016, 10:29:08 AM    Self test - passed
    Oct 25, 2016, 06:34:46 PM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/powerd_2016-10-25-183446_[redacted].crash
        /System/Library/CoreServices/powerd.bundle/powerd
    Oct 24, 2016, 06:01:17 PM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/powerd_2016-10-24-180117_[redacted].crash
    Oct 24, 2016, 05:45:06 PM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/powerd_2016-10-24-174506_[redacted].crash
    Oct 23, 2016, 06:33:43 PM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/powerd_2016-10-23-183343_[redacted].crash
    Oct 23, 2016, 06:10:16 PM    /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/powerd_2016-10-23-181016_[redacted].crash
```

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of this problem, but there's multiple reasons it can occur (e.g. A recent password change, using a Hackintosh system, a corrupted OS X installation, etc).

I checked the other post you referenced and one obvious solution not mentioned was to reset your PRAM/NVRAM.

To do this:

- Shut down your computer completely
- Switch it back on and quickly press and hold the <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>  keys until you hear the startup chime a second time.
- Let go of the keys and let your Mac startup normally

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. mouse speed, time and date/timezone, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  This is my mother's old macbook and I'll have to talk her through the reset (can't do it with remote desktop).  I'll report back the results.

Comment: OK, had her do the pram reset and still the same result logging into iCloud.  I know the reset worked since she remarked at how loud the chime sound was than normal.  Unfortunately, I'm stuck again :(

Comment: Ok, so is there anything your mum can think of that may coincide with this issue? Did she change a password? Did she update OS X Mavericks recently? Anything else she can think of? Also, it's not clear from your question, was she able to log in previously on the MacBook Pro?